# From a Lutheran perspective, how can we attain unity of mind while disagreeing with our brothers and sisters?

Tags: protestantism, lutheranism

In 1 Peter 3:8 Peter writes, "Finally, all of you, have unity of mind" (ESV), which I believe is a clear call for unity of mind within the church.

In Romans 14:5 Paul writes that, "Each one should be fully convinced in his own mind", (ESV) encouraging believers to hold fast to their beliefs.

How does the Lutheran church approach the issue of maintaining or establishing unity of mind across the church, even as each member strives to be fully convinced of their own beliefs?

In answering please provide concrete examples of how the Lutheran church attempts to achieve unity of mind. In particular please discuss how it does so while allowing each member of the church to honour God by being fully convinced of their own beliefs. It might also be helpful to elaborate on what is meant by 'unity of mind'.

Comment: This is a huge topic spanning many different aspects of ecclesiology and you want it covered from _all_ the different theological traditons using the umbrelna term "Chsistian"? This is far too broad #or this format. What are you really interested in here? What theological framework are you using yourself and what traditions are you actually trying to learn about?

Comment: I hope that someday people will learn the Parable of the Weeds, it answers this question regardless of denomination. The field is each Christian who is listening, the wheat is the truth, and the weeds are the errors, pointing out not to correct errors for the risk of uprooting the truth. Until the fullness of the message has been given. https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+13:24-30

Comment: If we are all mature or maturing Christians, ultimately we will come to agreement on the substantive issues.  There is one answer.  I have visited or attended many different denominations- Lutheran, Wesleyan, Presbyterian, Roman Catholic, multiple Baptist flavors, Church of Christ, Episcopal, Assemblies of God, charismatic, full gospel, Methodist and others.  Among the great churches I have found far more in common than differences between denominations.  A church of Christ minister once told me he agreed with the Baptist pastor on 99% of issues.  I guess it boils down to maturing in Christ.

Comment: You should probably restate your question in terms of governance procedures. I know very little about Lutheranism, but I do know that they have synods (meetings where the leaders come into agreement on major issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's  important to remember that one can disagree with their brothers and sisters in Christ about things that are not essential to the faith. For instance, there will be disagreements amongst Christians about whether baptism should be full immersion, or simply a sprinkling of water. This is not essential to the faith, meaning this does not determine whether a person is a Christian.

Something that is essential to the faith is that Christ died on the cross and rose again. If a person does not believe this they cannot be a Christian.

I think what these verses are saying is that each person should figure out the non-essentials of the faith on their own, and if their brother or sister disagrees with their viewpoint they should not let it divide them. To me, unity of mind means to come together with other members of the Church simply because they love the Lord and they want to worship Him together. Disagreeing on small things is healthy, and it opens minds.

I hope this answers your question. I decided to answer this question considering Christianity at large instead of through a Lutheran lens because it seemed to fit better with the verses you were asking about.

"But God has so composed the body, giving greater honor to the part that lacked it, that there may be no division in the body, but that the members may have the same care for one another." 1 Corinthians 12:24-25

Comment: Does this represent a Lutheran perspective?

Comment: Thanks Rebecca for your concise and comprehensive answer. Essentials and non-essentials, unity and diversity it seems to boil down to.